# How can I wrap every every express route handler with another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, apply

Basically I want to instead of this...

```
app.get(routes.test, function(req, res, next){
  actualRouteHandler(req, res, next) // Always returns a promise or throws.
    .catch(function(err) {
      next(err);
    });
});
```

Have this: 
`app.get(routes.test, catchWrap(actualRouteHandler));`

Or something similar, I've tried messing around with fn.apply and things but I can't find a way to pass actualRouteHandler the correct parameters (req,res,next) and still have the function. Do I need to return a function or something similar?

Edit: I think there may be libraries that do this but we have no access to the actual express application in this bit of code.

Comment: No, we can add middleware and routes as we please but can't say... use Express Promise Router (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router) as we don't have access to the actual express application, we can only build upon it which is far from ideal.

Comment: Oh, cool, I can answer that! :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your specific case, `catchWrap` would look like this:

```
function catchWrap(originalFunction) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        try {
            return originalFunction.call(this, req, res, next);
        } catch (e) {
            next(e);
        }
    };
}
```

That returns a new function that, when called, will call the original with your catch wrapper around it. The key parts are that it creates and returns a function (`return function(req, res, next) { ... };`) and this line:

```
return originalFunction.call(this, req, res, next);
```

`Function#call` calls the given function saying what to use as `this` during the call (in the above we pass on the `this` we recieved) and the arguments to use in the call.

You'd use it as you showed:

```
app.get(routes.test, catchWrap(actualRouteHandler));
```

Or if you prefer to define the actual handler as an anonymous function:

```
app.get(routes.test, catchWrap(function(req, res, next) {
    // ...handler code here...
}));
```

That `catchWrap` is specific to your situation, because you want to call `next(e)` with the exception if thrown. The *generic* form of "wrap this function in another function" is like this:

```
function catchWrap(originalFunction) {
    return function() {
        try {
            // You can do stuff here before calling the original...
            // Now we call the original:
            var retVal = originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
            // You can do stuff here after calling the original...
            // And we're done
            return retVal;
        } catch (e) {
            // you can do something here if you like, then:
            throw e; // Or, of course, handle it
        }
    };
}
```

`arguments` is a pseudo-array provided by JavaScript that includes all of the arguments that the current function was called with. `Function#apply` is just like `Function#call`, except you give the arguments to use as an array (or pseudo-array) rather than discretely.

---

Taking it a step further: You could create a function you passed a router to that returned an updated router that auto-wrapped the handlers when you called `get`, `post`, etc. Something along these lines (untested):

```
const routeCalls = ["all", "get", "post", "put", "delete", /*...*/];
function patchWithCatcher(router) {
    for (const call of routeCalls) {
        const original = router[call];
        // This seemingly-pointless object is to ensure that the new function
        // has a *name*; I don't know whether Express relies on the name of
        // the function you call (some libs with similar APIs do).
        const rep = {
            [call]: function (path, ...callbacks) {
                return router[call](path, ...callbacks.map(catchWrap));
            },
        };
        router[call] = rep[call];
    }
    return router; // Just for convenience
}
```

Using it:

```
const app = patchWithCatcher(express());
app.get(/*...*/);
app.post(/*...*/);
// ...
```

or

```
const router = patchWithCatcher(express.Router(/*...options...*/));
router.get(/*...*/);
router.post(/*...*/);
// ...
```

That monkey-patches the router you pass in. I considered using the passed-in router as the prototype of a new object in order to avoid modifying the router object passed in, but you'd have to test that really, really thoroughly, there are lots of edge cases around `this` during calls. Another viable alternative would be to use a `Proxy`, though at a runtime cost.

Comment: Amazing, it's moments like this you really wonder why you didn't think of these things yourself, you make it really simple there, cheers. 

Only thing I'd ask is about passing `this`, does that mean when I refer to this in the `originalFunction` it'll use the `this` from the outer function? What if I don't need to use `this`, can I just call the function normally?

Comment: The way it's written above, it'll use the `this` that Express used when calling our wrapper (the anonymous function `catchWrap` returns). So if Express used a specific `this`, we pass it along; if Express just called the function without doing anything to set `this`, `this` will be the global object (in loose mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode) and again we just pass it along. So the general pattern of `originalFunction.call(this, ...)` is usually best. But if you know `originalFunction` isn't expecting any particular `this`, yes, you could just call it directly.

Comment: I think express should do this by default. Currently it only captures synchronous errors, when most calls are asynchronous. BTW: If you are using Typescript I found Its better to use an arrow function so typescript uses the this of the context and doesn't complaint about having this as `any` type

Comment: @DanielCruz - I think they're busy with [koa](https://koajs.com/) (which does handle `async` functions). *Edit:* Well, [based on commits](https://github.com/koajs/koa), I guess they aren't. I have been wondering why I haven't been hearing that much about koa. So yes, they should, here in 2022, be handling `async` functions. :-)

Comment: (Mind you, I'm not complaining. Express v4 is fantastic and they did a great job on it, and I have my wrappers for `async` functions.)

Comment: This is a great answer to the content of the question but doesn't quite answer the title -- the title asks how to apply a wrapper to every route handler of a given router.  Do you know if there's a similar wrapper that could accept a *ROUTER* and decorate all the handlers?

Comment: @slifty - I don't think that's what the title's asking. But sure, you could write something that monkey-patched the router you passed into it, replacing the original `get`, `post`, `app`, etc. with versions that auto-wrapped their callbacks. I've added an example of that. If you mean going even further and monkey-patching the `express` function itself, you'd have to be sure to get in there "first" vs. other modules using it. Better to write a wrapper module an import from that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following simple approach can be used to setup a generic error handler -

Step 1: Write the error handler after registering your routes. So, for example, if you are registering your multiple routes like this:

```
config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/routes/modules/**/*.js').forEach(function (routePath) {
        require(path.resolve(routePath))(app);
    });
```

After registering the routes, you can setup a generic error handler -

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {

        // If the error object doesn't exists
        if (err != undefined) {
            //do error handling
        }
        else {
            //no error found
        }

    });
```

Step 2: In the route handler, you need to make sure that you call "next()" if no error is found. In case of error, you need to call "next(err)".

Comment: The problem is that each call could optionally raise an error in javascript. So if you forgot to catch one, you are also also not using `next(err)`, hence the need for some kind of catch all wrapper function.